# Граница слова preg_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не понимаю, почему находит простое слово, если я указал границу?

```
$str = 'http://site.ru, http://site.com, https://site.info sgdf';

echo preg_replace('#\b(https?://)([a-z0-9-]+)\.([a-z]{2,})\b#', '<a href="$1$2.$3">$2.$3</a>', $str);
```

Должно вывести site.ru, site.com, site.info

а выводит site.ru, site.com, site.info sgdf

Comment: А в такой ситуации `http://site.ru/contact`, что делать будете?

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/Iavmu4 - всё выводится верно:

```
<a href="http://site.ru">site.ru</a>, <a href="http://site.com">site.com</a>, <a href="https://site.info">site.info</a> sgdf
```

Вероятно ты не учёл, что замена - это именно замена совпадений, соответственно, всё что не совпало, остаётся на своих метах. Так порисходит с запятыми, пробелами и `sgdf`.

Comment: тогда надо использовать preg_match_all и потом выводить нужный массив?

Comment: Наверное да. Смотря что ты хочешь сделать.